# Kubernetes serviceAccounts and SELinux

Tags: kubernetes, selinux

We are running Kubernetes with SELinux enabled. We would like to use serviceAccounts. When I disable SELinux containers can read the secrets, as expected.

But, when I enable SELinux we cannot read the secrets inside the container. For example:

```
localhost$ kubectl exec -it my-pod bash
my-pod$ ls /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/
token
my-pod$ cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
Permission denied
```

What is the recommended way to use serviceAccounts with SELinux?

Thanks,
Andrej

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to run the following command to set the SELinux context correctly in the volumes directory.  I have an open issue to make this happen automatically in the future:

```
sudo chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /var/lib/kubelet
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: BTW, is it possible to use serviceAccounts for (deprecated) static PODs somehow?

Comment: You mean pods from a manifest file with a full kubernetes installation, or with a standalone kubelet?

Comment: We start Kubernetes static pods by starting kubelets on all nodes with the --config=/path/to/static/pods and placing Pod specifications in the directory. So the static Pods run in a full Kubernetes installation.

Comment: Just following up, i think we are going to try to handle this in the selinux policy for fedora/RHEL/CentOS

Answer (score 2):

There is an selinux policy rule for it (in Fedora 23 at least) but unfortunately it has a typo.

```
semanage fcontext -l | grep /var/lib/kub
/var/lib/kublet(/.*)?                              all files          system_u:object_r:docker_var_lib_t:s0
```

Should be "kubelet".  I opened a bug [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1331580).